# Merging Git Database Commits from One Branch to Another without Cherrypicking

Tags: sql-server, database, git, merge, version-control

We have main two Git branches at our company:
During our Sprint,

Everyone has (local branches)

Release branch: Contains prepared/developed code, ready for testing,  and

Master branch: Production- final ready code

I read in Git, Cherry picking is bad.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180312-00/?p=98215
http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2013/09/07/no-cherry-picking.html

After items are placed in master, they are ready to be deployed.
Sometimes , we do not move all Release items into Master, many reasons:, delay schedule, conduct more testing, late issues. What is the proper Git Devops strategy to only move certain items into Master? Should we backout commits, so we can do a clean merge?

Databases are different, as we are conducting change scripts, and not overwriting binaries like applications, etc.

Example:

Release branch *-------* ------------->   Master

Commit A, B, C, D, E   ------------->   Commit B,D

[Devops Stack](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/merging-git-database-commits-from-one-branch-to-another-without-cherrypicking)

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is apply the nonsequenced commits (like commit `B`, commit `D` while missing commit `C`) from `release` branch to `master` branch, you can checkout (“copy”) file versions from `release` branch to `master` branch.

Such as apply the changes from commit `B` on `release` branch to `master` branch, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout master
git checkout <commit B> -- .
git commit -m 'get the file version from commit B to master branch'
```

Now the latest commit on `master` branch contains the changes from commit `B`. And you can use the same way to apply the changes from commit `D` to `master` branch.